# "Twenty-four hour" or "twenty-four-hour?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

Which one is the correct form and why? Example sentence: x`

> Katsumi has already lived in this twenty-four(-)hour KFC for two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Twenty-four-hour*, because this is a [compound adjective](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/adjectives_compound_adjectives.htm).

Compare it with the numeral, so that there's only one spot where you have to think about putting a hyphen, and the necessity should become clearer:

> ✗ Let's visit the **24 hour KFC**.
>   
> ✓ Let's visit the **24-hour KFC**.